# Why the send-time is high with netNamedPipeBinding?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I use WCF to send data from sever to client.

1. Both server and client are C# applications.
2. I use `DuplexChannelFactory`.
3. The server broadcasts the data (array of bytes `byte[]`) every 40ms.
4. The size of the data varies between 70B and 6KB.
5. Both server and client run on the same machine. Therefore, I use `netNamedPipeBinding` and I don't need security.
6. I set the sizes of the buffers in binding to the max.
7. The machine is a strong server with strong cpu.

Every time the server sends a data, it sends also a timestamp. That's way I can calculate how long it took for each data to arrive to the client.

My log shows that, for the first 20 arrays, it takes 3-4 seconds for each array to arrive to the client. After that, the **send-time** drops down to 0-2ms and most of the time it stays 0-2ms. But, sometimes it rises up again and can be between 30ms and 1 second.

I don't need any transport and message security. I need for the data to be send from the server to client as fast as possible.

Can you suggest what can be the problem and how to configure the binding for that?

**UPDATE**

I suspect that this happens because of thread creation time. But, I tried to create 50 threads in `ThreadPool` before running the server and the client, but it still was slow at the beginning.

Comment: I suspect that this happens because of thread creation time. But, I tried to create 50 threads in `TreadPool` before running the server and the client and it still was slow at the beginning.

Comment: As usual in WCF: please enable logs on the client side and you'll be able to see all internal WCF machinery and check if something is slow there